# Obtaining input values as an array

Tags: jquery, html, serialization

I am making a website and i need to submit multiple values to a php file. 
Because I could select inputs with $('input') and call submit with ajax i did not make a form element.

I have a function in which i want to extract all input values and get a result as an array

I tried calling `$('input').serialize();` and setting the result to `$values` but it did not return an array and some of my values were missing (like the ones from select tags)

What is the best way to get an array from all the input fields that do not belong to any form element??

Comment: Whoever down voted this, should have left a comment as to why they down voted it ... perhaps they down voted it because more information about your problem is needed.  For example, how is your web page receiving input?  Is the input coming from an HTTP post?

Comment: `inputs` is not a tag in html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, the reason your `select` tags were left out is because you need to use the following selector:

```
$('input, select')
```

Secondly use `.serializeArray()` as

```
$('input, select').serializeArray();
```

Thirdly, you need to provide a `name` attribute to your elements. See http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/YV4Xe/

EDIT:
A better way to select input fields in general would be using the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector as suggested by @elclanrs

```
$(':input').serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the selector `inputs` which is not a valid HTML tag. You must manually list out each type of input that you wish to serialize.

```
$('input, select, textarea').serialize();
```